# When does 'truffle deploy' yield a different output every time?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, ganache, truffle-deployment

`truffle deploy` (aka `truffle migrate`) is documented [here](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations#running-migrations).

I'm doing the following sequence:

1. Starting a local Ganache node
2. Running `truffle deploy`

I'd expect this sequence to yield the exact same output (i.e., same contract addresses, same transaction hashes, and same gas costs) every time it is executed.

However, I clearly see a different output every time I execute it.

My question is - why? Is there some sort of randomness used by `truffle deploy`?

Here is my relevant configuration:

1. `ganache-cli --port=8545 --gasLimit=0xfffffffffff`
2. `truffle deploy --network=production`

The `production` network is configured in file `truffle-config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        production: {
            host:       "127.0.0.1",
            port:       8545,
            network_id: "*",          // Match any network id
            gasPrice:   100000000000, // Gas price used for deploys
            gas:        6721975,      // Gas limit used for deploys
        }
    }
};
```

Thank you!